# Grid does not properly size itself

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having issues with CollectionView and [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) in my Xamarin Forms application. The CollectionView height does not size itself properly, the elements inside overlaps. I tried everything without success.

Here's the Grid page XAML definition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Name="this"
         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         x:Class="RuberoydLabs.WallettoX.Controls.EventCell.EventCell">
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="SpendingEventWrapper"
          BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
                     WidthRequest="35"
                     HeightRequest="35"
                     Margin="5,0,0,0"
                     StrokeThickness="0"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1" />
            <Label AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                   Margin="5,-2,0,0"
                   x:Name="UserInitials"
                   TextColor="#0D495A" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Orientation="Vertical"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding InputEvent.Title}" 
                   FontSize="15"
                   x:Name="TitleLabel"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   TextColor="#24838E" />
            <Label Text="{Binding InputEvent.Category.Name}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   x:Name="CategoryLabel"
                   Margin="0,-4,0,0"
                   BackgroundColor="#C59B59"
                   Padding="4,2,4,2"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   TextColor="White" />
            <Label x:Name="CommentLabel"
                   Text="{Binding InputEvent.Comment}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   Margin="0,-4,0,0"
                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   TextColor="#959595" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Orientation="Vertical"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding InputEvent.Amount, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                   Margin="0,5,10,0"
                   TextColor="#2F2F2F"
                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
            <Label Text="{Binding InputEvent.MoneyAccount.Currency}"
                   Margin="0,-5,10,0"
                   FontSize="11"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   TextColor="#ADADAD"
                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 HeightRequest=".5"
                 BackgroundColor="#BABABA"  />
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

and here's my CollectionView XAML definition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:RuberoydLabs.WallettoX.Controls.EventCell;assembly=RuberoydLabs.WallettoX"
         xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:RuberoydLabs.WallettoX;assembly=RuberoydLabs.WallettoX"
         x:Class="RuberoydLabs.WallettoX.Views.DashboardPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 Orientation="Vertical">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
                        IsGrouped="True"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:EventCell InputEvent="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Padding="5,0,5,3"
                                 Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                 BackgroundColor="#E3E3E3">
                        <Label FontSize="12"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               TextColor="#767676"
                               Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dddd MMMM d, yyyy}'}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <CollectionView.GroupFooterTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="0,0,10,0"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{x:Static resources:StringLocalization.Balance}"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DayBalanceFormatted}"
                               HorizontalOptions="End" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupFooterTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

For some reason, the elements inside the list just overlaps. What's interesting, it looks different on Android and iOS.

This is how it looks like on iOS:

[image]

[image]

And this is how it looks like on Android, it adds weird space between cells if the label spans to two or more lines:

[image]

I tried almost everything: removing different kind of grid elements (like ellipsis, box view), tried all possible combinations of `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions`, removing `GroupHeaderTemplate` and `GroupFooterTemplate` alltogether, still the issue is there.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide one simple sample at github, I will download your sample to test at my side.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT please have a look https://github.com/vcartera81/XamarinFormsBug

Comment: As far as I can see everything is fine. I just tried to recreate this behavior in my environment also, but nothing strange. Neither android emulator, nor iOS simulator. One thing I would like to clarify. As I can see you provided iOS simulator screens.
Which iPhone simulator did you use? Have you tried on real devices?
From provided repo I've made a conclusion iOS version deployment target of your project is 8.0, am I right?

Comment: @Carteră Veaceslav I download your sample and to test, and I guess that there are some problems for AbsoluteLayout, I try to replace AbsoluteLayout using Frame to do it, but it still has some problem, you can try to do it.

Comment: @MoRRt did you tried the sample GitHub repo I've provided?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT even if I remove all that section with AbsoluteLayout, the issue is still there

Comment: @Carteră Veaceslav I guess that there may be a problem with collectionview, so you can report this problem at github for help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Xamarin forms is getting on my nerves!!! Contemplating to move to flutter

Comment: @user1034912 Yes, for me the issue was solved by upgrading to the latest Xamarin version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by upgrading to the latest Xamarin v5.0.0.2012